# iAd and other banners

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad, banner

In my application I'd like to show cycling iAd banners and another kind of "banners" made by myself.
The problem is that I don't know which could be the best practice.
I'd like to show iAd banner in a 5:1 ratio, that means for five of my banners I will show 1 time the iAd banner, every changes will be triggered by a timer of 10s. That means that the iAd banner will be hidden for 50 sec, shown for 10 and so on. 
Will Apple complain about that? does this influence my revenue in the iAd network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are artificially limiting the amount if time the iAd is shown (which is normally more than 10s), I believe you won't be paid for that impression.

A better solution would be to listen to the banner view's delegate and hide it *only when it tells you it can't find an ad*.

Comment: Yep it seems that you must show a banner for 30 sec to have an impression, I gues that I will change the logic and show iAd only if I don't have mine. Thanks